# Unable to Import Image library in Python code

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I trying to run a Data Science classification code in python but getting the following error and unable to install Image module in python

```
   Krishnas-MacBook-Air:src krishnalahoti$ python3 imageClassifier.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "imageClassifier.py", line 5, in <module>
        import Image  # PIL
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing the statement:

```
import Image
```

by

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
```